# Get specific data from a JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

Suppose there is a JSON structure like below

```json
{
  "v": "2021",
  "Outeritems": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "c": "r",
          "KeyOne": "DataOne",
          "KeyTwo": "DataTwo",
          "items": [
            {
              "c": "r",
              "KeyOne": "DataThree",
              "KeyTwo": "DataFour",
              "v": "F",
              "h": "N",
              "l": "N:"
            },
            {
              "c": "r",
              "KeyOne": "DataFive",
              "KeyTwo": "DataSix",
              "v": "T"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I read all **KeyOne** and its corresponding **KeyTwo**(line below KeyOne) using linq or some method. They may be nested in any of **items** array.  We need to get all such properties as a dictionary or key value pair like that.  Thanks for help.

Comment: A little Odd data structure, seems you could have a undetermined deep complexity depending of the (seemingly) aleatory presence or absence of the items list in any branch. So perhaps you need a effficient way to trasverse a non deterministic tree, the Data structure (a couple lists, Dictionary, ...) where you keep the result of KeyOne & KeyTwo seems trivial to me

Comment: How can we traverse all nodes of a json string using c#? Even nested nodes should be traversed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead commenting out, lets build an aprox answer.
Actually the better aproach is deserialize the JSON to a class with only the relevant properties, instead trying to use all the JSON structure.

Like:

```
    private class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("KeyOne")]
        public string KeyOne { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("KeyTwo")]
        public string KeyTwo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    private class Outeritem
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    private class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("Outeritems")]
        public List<Outeritem> Outeritems { get; set; }
    }
```

Then deserialize like:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Then for transverse the tree you can use a recursive aproach (just because a JSON string is a rather finite structure, not a good aproach in ALL cases)

```
List<string> KeyOneValues = new List<string>();
List<string> KeyTwoValues = new List<string>();
trasverseNode(List<Item> item)
{
  if (item.KeyOne != null) KeyOneValues.Add(item.KeyOne);
  if (item.KeyTwo != null) KeyTwoValues.Add(item.KeyTwo);
  foreach (Item child in item.Items)
  {
    trasverseNode(child); //<-- recursive
  }
}
```